# SageMath: running `make` ends with ImportError in dochtml phase

Tags: python, python-2.7, sage

I am trying to install sagemath package in my macbook. I entered
`./configure` followed by `make`. Here are the last few
lines of output. Couldn't debug the cause.

```
[sagelib-8.7] Finished cleaning, time: 0.40 seconds.
[sagelib-8.7] if [ "$UNAME" = "CYGWIN" ]; then                         \
[sagelib-8.7]       sage-rebase.sh "$SAGE_LOCAL" 2>/dev/null;            \
[sagelib-8.7]   fi
[sagelib-8.7] 
[sagelib-8.7] real  19m37.851s
[sagelib-8.7] user  59m16.416s
[sagelib-8.7] sys   2m58.759s
cp /Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/src/bin/sage-env-config /Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/local/bin/sage-env-config
cd ../.. && sage-logger -p './sage --docbuild --no-pdf-links all html ' logs/dochtml.log
[dochtml] Traceback (most recent call last):
[dochtml]   File "/Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
[dochtml]     mod_name, _Error)
[dochtml]   File "/Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
[dochtml]     __import__(mod_name)  # Do not catch exceptions initializing package
[dochtml]   File "/Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage_setup/docbuild/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
[dochtml]     import sage.all
[dochtml]   File "/Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/all.py", line 98, in <module>
[dochtml]     from sage.symbolic.all   import *
[dochtml]   File "/Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/symbolic/all.py", line 3, in <module>
[dochtml]     from sage.libs.pynac.pynac import I
[dochtml]   File "sage/symbolic/expression.pxd", line 4, in init sage.libs.pynac.pynac (build/cythonized/sage/libs/pynac/pynac.cpp:30147)
[dochtml]   File "sage/symbolic/expression.pyx", line 161, in init sage.symbolic.expression (build/cythonized/sage/symbolic/expression.cpp:74075)
[dochtml] ImportError: dlopen(/Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/symbolic/ring.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZNSt3__16vectorIN5GiNaC2exENS_9allocatorIS2_EEE11__vallocateEm
[dochtml]   Referenced from: /Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/symbolic/ring.so
[dochtml]   Expected in: flat namespace
[dochtml]  in /Users/satya/Downloads/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/symbolic/ring.so
make[3]: *** [doc-html] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-start] Error 2

real    19m41.468s
user    59m18.862s
sys 3m0.256s
***************************************************************
Error building Sage.

The following package(s) may have failed to build (not necessarily
during this run of 'make all-start'):

The build directory may contain configuration files and other potentially
helpful information. WARNING: if you now run 'make' again, the build
directory will, by default, be deleted. Set the environment variable
SAGE_KEEP_BUILT_SPKGS to 'yes' to prevent this.

make[1]: *** [all-start] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're much more likely to get a helpful response to your post in the `sage-devel` Google group than here.

Answer (score 1):

Running `make` for SageMath proceeds in two steps: `make build`
followed by `make doc`.

In your case, the `make build` phase seems to have completed,
and there was an issue only in the `make doc` phase.
This means you probably already have a functional SageMath,
with the drawback that the documentation failed to build.
So you might decide to try and use it as is.

Following @John Palmieri, I would recommend posting to sage-devel
or sage-support to get help debugging the make failure. It will
be useful to specify the operating system on which it occurred
(what version of macOS), if the buid was started from a directory
obtained by `git clone` or from a source tarball, what exact
sequence of operations were run.

Also, on your next attempt, you might want to move the SageMath
folder out of the Downloads folder before you run `make`, since
a Sage installation cannot be moved after it has been started once
(if Sage is moved, one has to run make again before it can be used).

Answer (score 0):

Building off Samuel's answer, a different thing you might want to try is simply to run `make doc-clean` and then `make doc` again.  I have found that (on Mac) there is sometimes a weird burp I can never track down, and this usually gets past it.